# QStackWidget navigate from page1 to page 2

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qstackedwidget

I have a base class `MainWindow` which inherits from `QMainWindow` . 
`MainWindow` has `QSTackedWidget` in its Ui file. I have `Page1` and `Page2` in different classes All page widgets in there are seperate classes derived from `QWidget`.

`QMainWindow` implements `QStackedWindow` in one class. All other pages inside the stacked widget are added classes and all have there own .ui filled with buttons

I implemented

```
Page1* page1obj = new Page1;
Page2* page2obj = new Page2;



ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(0,page1obj);   
ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(1,page2obj);
```

it has a ui file which has next button . On clicked it should be go to page 2;

**Page1.cpp**

```
connect(m_ui>nextButton,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Page1::onclicked);      

void Page1::onclicked()
{

    Mainwindow* obj = new MainWindow;
    obj->openPage2();  
}
```

The issue is on clicked button opens up a new window, not a single window in stacked format. Where am I going wrong?? How to fix this issue?

Comment: I corrected a typo.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you started with a statement of the problem, and gave a minimal complete example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that would help others diagnose the problem.

Comment: My apologies ..was new to stackoverflow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to make the change in MainWindow, you can do it from the pages.

When you insert a widget into a `QStackedWidget`, this is set as the parent widget, so we can access `QStackedWidget` with the `parentWidget()` method:

```
void Page1::onclicked()
{
    QStackedWidget *stack = qobject_cast<QStackedWidget* >(parentWidget());
    if(stack)
        stack->setCurrentIndex(1);
}
```

---

Update:

If you want to use `MainWindow` you do not have to create a `MainWindow`, but access it using the parental relationship and in the end make a casting

```
mainwindow
└── stackedwidget
    ├── page1
    └── page2
```

---

```
void Page1::onclicked()
{
    MainWindow *mainwindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow* >(parentWidget()->parentWidget());
    if(mainwindow)
        mainwindow->openPage2();
}
```

Comment: I need to send signal to Mainwindow.cpp to change to index to 1 . But using new operator it opens a up the Page2 as new pop up window rather than swapping from parent window to page 2

Comment: @Rubina 
Why do you need to send it to MainWindow ?, have you tried my solution?

Comment: MainWindow has the QStackedWidget and has all the pages in it so I need to send signal to Mainwindow to swap back and forth

Comment: @Rubina 
I have added another possible solution:

Comment: I tried your solution . it works well from moving from page 1 to page 2 but is  becomes irresponsive from page 2 to page 3 or page 2 to 1